# React Native Scroll position

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Scenario: There is a button outside the scroll view which will display but when I scroll down and reach the position of inner button it should hide the outer button and only display the inner button. What I have tried is to calculate the position which is not working.

```
const App = () => {
  const [positionOutside, setPositionOutSide] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
  const [hideButton, setHideButton] = useState(false);
  const handleScroll = event => {
    const y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    if (y >= positionOutside) {
      //as soon as scrolls to Inner Button hide Outer button
      setHideButton(true);
    } else {
      setHideButton(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        >
        {/* other components */}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onLayout={event => {
            const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
            setPositionOutSide({x: layout.x, y: layout.y});
          }}
           >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Inner Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
      {!hideUpperButton && (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Outer Button</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the vertical position of the inner button not the entire object and also you have to subsract the vertical offset with the offset from were the bottom button should be hidden, i am using container height which is gotten using useWeindowDimentions as offset

Eg:

```js
     if (y >= Math.abs(height - positionOutside.y)) {
      //as soon as scrolls to Inner Button hide Outer button
      if (!hideUpperButton) {
        setHideButton(true);
      }
    } else {
      if (hideUpperButton) {
        setHideButton(false);
      }
    }
```

live code

> [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/bold-yellow-mixed-nuts)